# Running multiple functions at once using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio

Currently, I am working on a text-based RPG.  The idea is to implement a sound track, as well as general sounds for gameplay, along with a gui, eventually.  I have figured out how to play sound using a pyaudio.  Now, the problem is that I cannot run any other functions while the music is playing.  Is there a way around this?  I have read threads on multiprocessing; however, they don't seem to be helping much.  With out the multiprocessing code, the audio will dominate and Python will not run any other function.  With the code, the game will run the game, but no the audio.

```
#Module Imports
from rooms import user, create
import items
import enemies
import rooms
from music import AudioFile
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys

def game():
    global AudioFile
    User = user()
    c = create()
    a = AudioFile("rpg.wav")
    while User.is_alive() and User.win == 0:
        if __name__=='__main__':
            p1 = Process(target = a.play)
            p1.start()
            p2 = Process(target = c)
            p2.start()
            p1.join()
            p2.join()
game()
```

Shouldn't this allow a.play() and class c() to run at the same time?

Thanks for any feedback and answers!

Comment: Did you get an answer? I am stuck with a exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pleae try following code,

```
while User.is_alive() and User.win == 0:
    if __name__=='__main__':
        procs = [Process(target = a.play), Process(target = c)]
        [p.start() for p in procs]
        [p.join() for p in procs]
```

Comment: That code legitimately does the same thing.  My game commands the player to type 'start' so they can start the game.  If I exit out of that prompt, the music will try to play, but ultimately gives me a 'Pickling' error.  I know the audio code works, because when executed alone it works fine.  However, in conjunction with the rest of the code, it doesn't seem to work.